# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar una fila en un dataframe mediante el valor de dos columnas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset

Tengo un data frame con la siguiente info:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tiene aproximadamente 1 millón de filas con los nombres de las compañías americanas el valor de su acción diarias desde hace 5 años. 
Lo que necesito es definir una función con dos argumentos (company name y date)la cual me devuelva la información de su fila completa. Por ejemplo: Activision Blizzard Inc y 2020-03-03 y que me devuelva el resto de la fila: 58.64, 58.90, 58.0900, 58.21 y 4825357.
No puedo iterar por índice de filas pues quiero hacer un programa que pregunte al usuario por el nombre de una compañía y una fecha y le devuelva la información del valor de su acción ese día.

Pd:Perdón por los errores que haya cometido (que seguro que son muchos) pero es mi primera publicación, acabo de iniciarme en este mundo. 
Gracias!

Comment: Hola, deberías poner el código de lo que tienes hecho hasta el momento.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre difinir la función así:

```
def devolver_fila(company,date):

    return df[(df['company name']==company)&(df['date']==date)]
```

La función recibe los dos argumentos, y devolverá la fila donde se cumple la condición de nombre de compañía y fecha.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
result = devolver_fila('Activision Blizzard Inc','2020-03-03')
```

En `result` se guardará la fila que deseada. y si le haces `print(result)` podrás ver su salida por pantalla

Si sólo deseas ver los registros de una sola compañía, sólo bastará con hacer:

```
def devolver_companya(company,date):

    return df[df['company name']==company]
```

El ejemplo de uso es idéntico a `devolver_fila`.

Puedes revisar algunos ejemplos: [Operaciones de filtrado](https://www.analyticslane.com/2019/05/10/operaciones-de-filtrado-de-dataframe-con-pandas-en-base-a-los-valores-de-las-columnas/)

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba!!!! Muchas gracias. Tenía algo bastante parecido pero no daba con el error!! Gracias!